# Find odd divisor

Tags: python, division

There is a function, which find first odd divisor then return 'YES' or return 'NO':

```
def find_del(a: int) -> str:
"""return 'YES' if number have odd divisor else 'NO'."""
if a % 2 != 0:
    return 'YES'
else:
    x = 'NO'
    for j in range(3, a):
        if (a % j == 0 and j % 2 != 0) or (a / j == 0):
            x = 'YES'
            break
    return x
```

But this function doesn't work fast for number 1099511627776.

How to change the function to make it work?

Comment: Your function (assuming that's what you want it to do) returns NO for powers of 2 and YES otherwise. This can reduced down to one mathematical expression.

Comment: 1099511627776 is a power of two and has no odd divisors. If we assume that you can make one iteration per microsecond, your loop would take almost two weeks to complete. I suspect that you need to apply The Ancient Power of Maths.

Comment: Hint: if `x` is even, the smallest odd divisor of `x` is also the smallest odd divisor of `x/2`. (And the `range` function has an optional 'step' parameter, which can cut your work in half.)

Answer (score 0):

Thanks 'molbdnilo' for tip, I changed my program:

```
def find_del(a: int) -> str:
"""return Yes if number have odd divisor else No"""
    while a % 2 == 0:
        a = a // 2
    return 'YES' if a != 1 else 'NO'
```

Now it works even for large numbers like 1099511627776.